# Expected number of trials until all categories are observed at least once in a multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, multinomial-distribution

The title basically sums up my question, but suppose I have a multinomial distribution with k categories. What is the expected number of trials until I observe every category occur at least once? Essentially what is the trial at which I'm expected to, for the first time, have observed every category occur.

---

I.E.:

k = 4 categories with probabilities (1 = 0.1, 2 = 0.2, 3 = 0.3, 4 = 0.4)

A possible string of observations which is satisfactory is:

4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1 [In which case 9 draws were observed]

Another would be:

3, 1, 3, 4, 2 [In which case 5 draws were observed]

---

I know how this would work for bernoulli trials (geometric / negative binomial relationships), but for multinomial I wasn't able to find an easy solution.

Comment: This is the *[coupon collector](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector) problem* with differing rarity. I believe there are a number of posts related to this problem on site. See also the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem) for some basic information (your problem is mentioned in the section on generalizations).